# How can I create a (100%) stacked histogram in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram

#### My dataset:

I have data in the following format (here, imported from a CSV file). You can find an example dataset as CSV [here](http://cl.ly/3F1u0W2b3y081v172A2O).

```
PAIR   PREFERENCE
1      5
1      3
1      2
2      4
2      1
2      3
```

… and so on. In total, there are 19 pairs, and the `PREFERENCE` ranges from `1` to `5`, as discrete values.

---

#### What I'm trying to achieve:

What I need is a stacked histogram, e.g. a 100% high column, for each pair, indicating the distribution of the `PREFERENCE` values.

Something similar to the "100% stacked columns" in Excel, or (although not quite the same, a so-called "mosaic plot"):

[image]

---

#### What I tried:

I figured it'd be easiest using `ggplot2`, but I don't even know where to start. I know I can create a simple bar chart with something like:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=factor(PAIR), y=factor(PREFERENCE))) + geom_bar(position="fill")
```

… that however doesn't get me very far. So I tried this, and it gets me somewhat closer to what I'm trying to achieve, but it still uses the count of `PREFERENCE`, I suppose? Note the `ylab` being "count" here, and the values ranging to 19.

```
qplot(factor(PAIR), data=d, geom="bar", fill=factor(PREFERENCE_FIXED))
```

Results in:

[image]

- So, what do I have to do to get the stacked bars to represent a histogram?
- Or do they actually do this already?
- If so, what do I have to change to get the labels right (e.g. have percentages instead of the "count")?

<sub>By the way, this is not really related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2405575/435093), and only marginally related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241290/stacked-area-histogram-in-r) (i.e. probably same idea, but not continuous values, instead grouped into bars).</sub>

Comment: You mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619067/stacked-bar-chart-in-r-ggplot2-with-y-axis-and-bars-as-percentage-of-counts

Comment: @RomanLuštrik It's very similar, but the solution, adapted with my two variables, [outputs something weird](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2AJy2.png). Do you have any idea on how to proceed? I guess I'm almost there, I (probably) only need to change the scale to percentage.

Comment: A nit:  this is not at all a histogram, and in fact bar charts are not histograms.  That said, if the total 'count' for each factor is in fact 19, then yes, you're done.  replace count with, say `ctpercent<-100*count/19` to get the desired y-values.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Well, I know the terminology is a bit off. Where exactly should I put `ctpercent<-100*count/19` in the `qplot` command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_bar(data = dat,
             aes(x = factor(PAIR),fill = factor(PREFERENCE)),
             position = "fill")
```

where I've read your data into `dat`. This outputs something like this:

[image]

The y label is still "count", but you can change that manually by adding:

```
+ scale_x_discrete("Pairs") + scale_y_continuous("Votes")
```

Comment: ...or simply `labs(x = "Pairs",y = "Votes")`.